# Fix oversized text inside a block diagram (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

the following code produces a block diagram which is too long for the page size. Is there a way to make the four blocks below be written in two lines?

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \node [block] (a) {Quantidade Medida};
    \node [block] (b) [right=of a] {Elemento de comparação};
    \node [block] (c) [right=of b] {Elemento de decisão};
    \node [block] (d) [right=of c] {Elemento de ação};
    \node [block] (e) [above=of b] {\textit{Threshold}};
    %\node [coordinate] (d) [right of=c, node distance=3cm]{};
    \path[->] (a) edge (b);
    \path[->] (b) edge (c);
    \path[->] (c) edge (d);
    \path[->] (e) edge (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Diagrama de blocos de um relé}\label{diagramablocosrele}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Block diagram]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add align=right to the block parameters and use \\ where you want the break to occur in each label text should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you liked:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm,
block/.style = {draw, text width=21mm, align=center}
                ]
\node [block] (a) {Quantidade Medida};
\node [block] (b) [right=of a] {Elemento de comparação};
\node [block] (c) [right=of b] {Elemento de decisão};
\node [block] (d) [right=of c] {Elemento de ação};
\node [block] (e) [above=of b] {\textit{Threshold}};
%
\path[->]   (a) edge (b) 
            (b) edge (c)
            (c) edge (d)
            (e) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```